# RewriteCond - load index.html from subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rewrite rule that redirects me to a sub folder and loads the index.html

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

SetEnvIf HOST        ^sub.mydomain.de          allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.mydomain.de$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder [L,R=301]
```

so far: this works - but it show the /folder/ inside the url - is it possible
to "hide" the /folder/ in url?

Does somebody has an hint for me?.

Thanks
marek

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `R=301` bit from the rule so that it looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder [L]
```